# databound dropdownlist select an item

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a databound dropdown list (ASP.net). I want the page to load with a certain item as the selected item.

I am not adding a blank first row (thats not what i need)
I find that I can get this to work with "AppendDataBoundItems" to true, but the side-effect is that I have all the items listed twice.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Page_PreRender event to handle this situation....

In the Page_Load register an event handler for the PreRender event

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Page.PreRender += new EventHandler(Page_PreRender);

 }
```

And in the PreRender event,

```
void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 ComboBoxSomething.SelectedValue = WhatEverYouWant;

}
```

Comment: Would I still keep the AppendDataBoundItems to true? Also It appears there is an existing handler for prerender - would i still need the first part?

Comment: I don't think you will need the AppendDataBoundItems property be set to true. And Also, you can put the code inside the existing event. Can you post the code you have currently so we can see if everything is ok :)